# SQL - Getting date with one digit for day and month

Tags: sql, date, format

I need a date in the following format: 1.1.2018
So no leading 0 if not needed. I checked the date formats and it doesn't exist this way.

My way would be to build a stored proc or function, converting the date to a varchar and deleting the 0 if needed.

Is there a better solution where I can already get that result without building a stored proc / function?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: depends on the dbms being used. please tag accordingly.

Comment: Tag the database you are using.  Also, because clear what the format is . . . is it m.d.yyyy or d.m.yyyy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--if you are using MSSQL Server 
select getdate() 'getdate', (cast(month(getdate()) as varchar)+'.'+cast(day(getdate()) as varchar)+'.'+ cast(year(getdate()) as varchar)) 'getdate_new_format'
```